# Change image on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry about the vague title but I'm not really sure how to describe this.

What I want to do is onclick, change the image. Here is that portion of the code.

Can someone tell me if this is possible? I don't see a way to do this because I'm not sure how to reference the anchor tag.

```
$(document.createElement('a'))
  .attr('href', '#')
  .html('<img src="myimage.jpg" />')
  .click( function( e ){
    // When the user clicks the anchor tag above, I want to replace the current
    // image (myimage.jpg) with another one.
  }
```

Comment: change the src attribute

Comment: you have to add it to the DOM to make it even clickable

Comment: Thanks Scott. I can do that but here's the issue I think I see with that. This anchor tag sits inside of a table row and there are many rows in this grid. How would I correctly identify the right a tag?

Comment: Now my comment makes no sense...

Comment: @Gavin, it's a good thing I'm not a very literal person or I may have actually gone out and bought a suit thinking it would have fixed my issue. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to retain the state of the code in which it is written (which is horrible), `e.currentTarget` is a reference to the element that is being clicked. You can use that to repeat your (discouraged) `.html()` procedure with another image URL.

```
$(document.createElement('a'))
    .attr('href', '#')
    .html('<img src="myimage.jpg" />')
    .click( function( e ){
        $(e.currentTarget).html('<img src="myimage2.jpg" />');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I was close. I'm really new to the DOM and as I was looking through it, I noticed it and figured I could use it. I was going about it all wrong though now that I can see how you're doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just to give the image a class, like, "myImg", and use the `.on()` method to bind to dynamically created elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.myImg', function(){
    //$(this) refers to the image that we clicked
    $(this).prop('src', 'http://my-domain.com/path/to/my/new-image.jpg');
});
```

This binds the event to the document, and anytime an image with the class of "myImg" is clicked, it will replace the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.createElement('a'))
  .attr('href', '#')
  .html('<img src="myimage.jpg" />')
  .click( function( e ){
      $(this).find('img').attr('src','myNewImage.jpg');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//create node
$('<a>', {
   'href': '#',
   'src': 'myimage.jpg'
})

//add it to the body
.appendTo('body')

//add envent
.on('click', function(){
   $(this).attr('src', 'otherimage.jpg');

   //prevent to jump to the top of the page caused by the '#'
   return false;
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I like it. I'm going to give this a try as well. Thank you for this

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple one

```
$('img').click(function () {
 $(this).attr('src', 'src/to/new/file.png');
}
```

If you want to change the image when click is over the `a`. Then use

```
$('a').click( function () {
```

instead of the image one.

That will change the src attribute of the current image.

Here is a working fiddle for this :)

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/8H4MC/

You will se when the mouse is hovered over the image, it changes. You can use `click` instead of `hover`. That should work. And don't create `a` if you have to disable it using `href="#"`.

If you want a cursor of pointer use `cursor: pointer` in CSS or use

```
$(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```